# Ruby CGI Stream Audio

Tags: ruby, streaming, cgi

What I want to do is use a CGI script (written in Ruby) to read a binary file off of the filesystem (audio, specifically) and stream it to the browser.

This is how I am doing that so far,

```
require 'config'

ENV['REQUEST_URI'] =~ /\?(.*)$/
f= $config[:mdir] + '/' + $1.url_decode
f = File.open f, 'rb'

print "Content-Type: audio/mpeg\r\n"#TODO: Make it guess mime type
print "\r\n"

#Outputs file
while blk = f.read(4096)
    $stdout.puts blk
    $stdout.flush
end

f.close
```

It's not perfect, there are security holes (exposing the whole filesystem..), but it just isn't working right. It's reading the right file, and as far as I can tell, outputting it in 4k blocks like it should. Using Safari, if I go to the URL, it will show a question mark on the audio player. If I use wget to download it, it appears to work and is about the right size, but is corrupted. It begins playing fine, then crackles, and then stops.

How should I go about doing this? Do I need to Base-64 encode, if can I do that without loading the whole file into memory in one go?

Btw, this is only going to be used over local area network, and I want easy setup, so I'm not interested in a dedicated streaming server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use `IO#print` instead of `IO#puts` but this has some disadvantages.

## Don't do the file handling in ruby

Ruby is not good in doing stupid tasks very fast. With this code, you will probably not be able to fill your bandwith.

### No CGI

All you want to do is expose a part of the filestystem via http, here are some options on how to do it

- Set your document root to the folder you want to expose.
- Make a symlink to the folder you want to expose.
- Write some kind of rule in your webserver config to map certain url's to a folder

Use any of these and the http server will do for you what you want.

### X-Sendfile

Some http servers honor a special header called X-Sendfile. If you do

```
print "X-Sendfile: #{file}"
```

the server will use the specified file as body. In lighty this works only through fastcgi, so you would need a fastcgi wrapper like: http://cgit.stbuehler.de/gitosis/fcgi-cgi/ . I don't know about apache and others.

### Use a c extension

C extensions are good at doing stupid tasks fast. I wrote a c extension which does nothing, but reading from one IO and writing it to another IO. With this c extension you can fill a GIGABIT Lan through ruby: git://johannes.krude.de/io2io

Use it like this:

```
IO2IO.do(file, STDOUT)
```

Comment: I'm not exposing the whole filesystem. Well, I am, if I add a .., but I plan on fixing that.

Comment: It seems I didn't read your code carefully enough. I fixed my answer according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

[`puts`](http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/ref_c_io.html#IO.puts) is for writing "lines" of "text", and therefore [appends a newline](http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/ref_c_io.html#IO.puts) to whatever you give it (turning your mpegs into garbage). You want [`syswrite`](http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/ref_c_io.html#IO.syswrite).

Comment: `IO#syswrite` is pretty lowlevel. You have to check whether the complete block was written. I would use `IO#print` instead.